# dijit.dialog is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, dojo

i have a old ZendApplication (ZF1) and now i try to transfer this App to ZF3.
In the App i use some Dojo Elements, e.g. Helpdialog.
In ZF3 Dojo is not supported directly by Zend, so i use Dojo direct wihtout Zend Interaction.

So, in my Layout View i load Dojo like this:

```
<script src="<?= $this->basePath()?>/assets/custom/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true,isDebug: true,parseOnLoad: true">

require ([
    'dijit/Dialog',
    'dijit/form/Button',
    'dijit/form/SimpleTextarea',
....
  'dojox/widget/Standby',
  'dojo/domReady!',
],)
);
```

This is the code i want to use:

```
       require (['dojo/domReady!','dijit/Dialog']);
          function showHelp(id,help) {
                dojo.xhrGet({
                    url: "http://localhost/NeuesProjekt/public/test/test",
                    //url:"http://localhost/NeuesProjekt/public/", // baseUrl + "/help/index/charkey/" + id,
                    load: function(data) {
                            helpDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
                                title: "help",
                                content: "data",
                                style: "width: 550px;"
                            });
                            helpDlg.show();
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                            var data = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
                            helpDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
                                title: "help",
                                content: "data2",
                                style: "width: 550px"
                            });
                            helpDlg.show();
                    }
                });

            };
```

It will work until the App comes to `new dijit.Dialog` there i got the Error *dijit.dialog is not a constructor*

Where is my mistake?

EDIT: 
In my views i call the function in a anchor like these: '  href="javascript:showHelp('Help')">HELP'

EDIT2:
I F12 debug it tels me Dialog is not defined, but dijit was found.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a mix of pre 1.7 dojo style and the 1.7 + one (see for example [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/require.html) for the use of require before 1.7 and after). Since I see 'async: true', you are using a version od dojo > = 1.7. See [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/loader/amd.html) how to use correctly the dojo AMD loader. The way you use the require statement, you are not sure the corresponding modules will be loaded when you use them (it is asynchronous). This may be why you get an error on new dijit.dialog. The proper way is:

```
require ([dijit/Dialog, dojo/domReady!], function(Dialog){
    ...
    var helpDlg = new Dialog({...});
    helpDlg.show();
});
```

Note that the convention is to put dojo/domReady! last (see [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html)). Note also that dojo.xhrGet(...) is deprecated (see [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/xhrGet.html)) ... which does not mean it won't work (I am not familiar with pre 1.7 style).

Edited to answer your comment below:

```
require ([dijit/Dialog, dojo/domReady!], function(Dialog){
    var showHelp = function(id, help){
        ...
        var helpDlg = new Dialog({...});
        ...
        helpDlg.show();
        ...
    }
    showHelp(1, 'please help me!');
});
```

Comment: i try to use it in this way:            require (['dijit/Dialog','dojo/domReady!'],
          function showHelp(id,help) {   but then i got the Error showHelp is not defined.

Comment: I edited my answer. : require loads dijit/Dialog, and then when done calls function(Dialog), which creates the function showHelp in the local variable showHelp, and then executes it (last statement).

Answer (score -1):

I found my mistake. i have only change the requirements for Dojo, so it will work:
`dojo.require ('dijit.form.Button');`